# How to print an entity-relationship (ER) diagram using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship

Using Oracle SQL Developer, how do we print the generated entity-relationship (ER) diagram?

(Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.3.20)

Comment: Thanks Ted, I meant for it to be a Question & Answer.. thanks for picking this up

Answer (score 2):

To print the generated entity-relationship (ER) diagram:

File --> Data Modeler --> Print Diagram --> To Image File or To PDF File

(Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.3.20)

To generate an ER diagram using Oracle SQL Developer, go to How to generate an entity-relationship (ER) diagram using Oracle SQL Developer